# Conditional statement in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to get some code to display based on a condition. I have a boolean field in a table called "show_weekly". What I'm attempting is: If the column == 1 then display the first line else display the 2nd line of code. for some reason it's only showing the 2nd line.

```
<% if @listing.show_weekly == 1 %>

<%= number_to_currency(@listing.price/4, :unit => "&pound;") %> / week

<% else %>

<%= number_to_currency(@listing.price, :unit => "&pound;") %> / month
<% end %>
```

any help is greatly appreciated. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to check if it equals `true`, not `1`

Answer (score 7):

The value of a boolean column will either be `false` or `true` in ruby, not `0` or `1`. So you should do:

```
<% if @listing.show_weekly %>
```

instead of `<% if @listing.show_weekly == 1 %>`

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest adding a method to your model

```
def print_price

   @p =  this.show_weekly? ? this.price / 4 : this.price 
   number_to_currency (@p, :unit => "&pound;")

end
```

Answer (score 2):

A boolean value is *stored* as a 1 or a 0, but it is always interpreted as `true` or `false` before being returned from the model. This is a source of a lot of confusion.

Using the accessor method `show_weekly?` can help because a question-mark in a method name usually indicates it will return a boolean value, or something that can be evaluated as boolean.

It will be a lot more readable if you have:

```
<% if @listing.show_weekly? %>
   ...
<% else %>
   ...
<% endif %>
```

Wherever possible, avoid comparing to specific hard-coded values. For instance, the following is redundant and yet I see it all the time:

```
# Example: Comparison to nil
if (@something == nil)

# Should be: Checking if initialized
if (@something)

# Example: Comparison to true
if (@something == true)

# Should be: Testing directly
if (@something)
```

As there are only two values that *evaluate as* false in Ruby, `nil` and `false`, it is generally the case that anything that is not true is nil. Occasionally you will have boolean columns that can be `true`, `false` or `nil` if it is not defined, but this is unusual and can trip up people.

Answer (score 0):

If `@listing.show_weekly` contains a boolean value, just test for true :

```
<% if @listing.show_weekly %>

.....

<% else %>

....

<% end %>
```

Notice you don't even need the "`== true`". This is because the IF statement only looks to see if there's a `true` value returned from whatever expression follows it. If `@listing.show_weekly` contains a value of `true` then that's all the IF statement sees if that's all you provide it.